# Displaying get_defined_vars() as an array which can contain html in values

Tags: php, debugging, multidimensional-array

As the title says, I want to make a "debug" site that displays the `get_defined_vars()` vars as an array.

It seems like some variables contain or can contain HTML or even dynamic code like PHP.

First I tried the classic:

```
<pre>
<?=print_r(get_defined_vars());?>
</pre>
```

then I played with `htmlentities()` and `htmlspecialchars()` commands and wrote this:

```
$allVars=get_defined_vars();
array_walk_recursive($allVars, function (&$value) {
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES);
});
print_r($allVars);
```

this takes forever and outputs a blank sheet :-)

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: A blank screen is a typical symptom of a PHP environment not being configured to display error messages. If you want to fix that first feel free to ask.

Comment: I have put this
`error_reporting(ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
`
But it still does not show errors. Its a AL_INCL sSERVER, I cant manipulate the PHP ini

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in your code. You may want to test `array_walk_recursive()`'s return value but, if no error messages are printed, it's hard to figure out what's wrong. Does it work in your dev environment and just crashes on the live server? Or the live server is the only server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try this :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL)
```

E_ALL not ALL ;-)